# how to fix bootstrap modal opacity error?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I just recently used "bootstrap modal" and I'm having problems in displaying the modal itself. The modal works fine. However, the modal backdrop appears to be solid black on its own. the modal backdrop should appear transparent on its own right? I honestly cannot find the error here.

here's the modal trigger code:

```
<label for="notes">
    <a href="#notes" data-toggle="modal">
        <i class="fa fa-sticky-note"></i> Create Notes
    </a>
</label>
```

here's the modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="notes" role="dialog"> <!-- modal -->
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <textarea name="note_title" placeholder="Your title here. 48 characters max only." pattern="{1,48}"></textarea>
                <textarea name="note_record"></textarea>
                <button type="submit" name="submit_notes" style="float: right;"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here's the output before the modal activates
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDjMi.jpg

here's the modal when activated (upon clicking the blue "create notes" a link)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEGvL.jpg

thank you for the possible answers, stackoverflow

Comment: Please check opacity for modal backdrop in developer console.

Comment: the modal-backdrop does not change the opacity either

Comment: can you add some sort of snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: here https://jsfiddle.net/7au6bL5w/

Comment: i found out the issue, its because of your bootstrap.min.js

Comment: what exactly is the problem in using bootstrap.min.js?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using Bootstrap-4 CSS while using Bootstrap-3's JS

using correct bootstrap.js library fixes this issue.

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here's the js fiddle for the same: https://jsfiddle.net/9c2u143s/

Comment: thanks for the very big help @Aditya Thakur. I really really appreciate it :)

Comment: Is the version are you using of bootstrap, i can't find the issue in GitHub, but if you update to > 4.0, you don't need add style opacity in you component